# Scala UDF runs fine on Spark shell but gives NPE when using it in sparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a sparkUDF. When I run it on spark-shell it runs perfectly fine. But when I register it and use in my sparkSQL query it gives NullPointerException.

---

**scala> *test_proc("1605","(@supp In (-1,118)")***

16/03/07 10:35:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 220) in 62 ms on cdts1hdpdn01d.rxcorp.com (1/1)

16/03/07 10:35:04 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 21.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool

16/03/07 10:35:04 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 21 (first at :45) finished in 0.062 s 16/03/07 10:35:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 16 finished: first at :45, took 2.406408 s

res14: Int = 1

scala>

---

But when I register it and use it in my sparkSQL query, it gives NPE.

**scala> *sqlContext.udf.register("store_proc", test_proc _)***

**scala> *hiveContext.sql("select store_proc('1605' , '(@supp In (-1,118)')").first.getInt(0)***

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: select store_proc('1605' , '(@supp In (-1,118)') 16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed 16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: first at :24

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 17 (first at :24) with 1 output partitions 16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 22(first at :24) 16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 22 (MapPartitionsRDD[86] at first at :24), which has no missing parents

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(10520) called with curMem=1472899, maxMem=2222739947

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_30 stored as values in memory (estimated size 10.3 KB, free 2.1 GB)

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(4774) called with curMem=1483419, maxMem=2222739947

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_30_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.7 KB, free 2.1 GB)

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_30_piece0 in memory on 162.44.214.87:47564 (size: 4.7 KB, free: 2.1 GB)

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 30 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 22 (MapPartitionsRDD[86] at first at :24)

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 22.0 with 1 tasks

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 22.0 (TID 221, cdts1hdpdn02d.rxcorp.com, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2155 bytes)

16/03/07 10:37:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_30_piece0 in memory on cdts1hdpdn02d.rxcorp.com:33678 (size: 4.7 KB, free: 6.7 GB)
16/03/07 10:37:58 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 22.0 (TID 221, cdts1hdpdn02d.rxcorp.com)**: java.lang.NullPointerException**

at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.parseSql(HiveContext.scala:291) at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:725) at $line20.$read$iwC$iwC$iwC$iwC$iwC$iwC$iwC$iwC.test_proc(:41)

---

This is **sample** of my 'test_proc':

**def test_proc**(x:String, y:String):Int = {

val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

val z:Int = hiveContext.sql("select 7").first.getInt(0)

return z 
}

Comment: link seems to require a signup, so you'd better give the details here. It's the kind thing to do, anyway :)

Comment: Hey buddy, sure. I have updated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output from a standalone call it looks like `test_proc` is executing some kind of Spark action and this cannot work inside UDF because Spark doesn't support nested operations on distributed data structures. If `test_proc` is using `SQLContext` this will result in NPP since Spark contexts exist only on the driver.

If that's the case you'll have restructure your code to achieve desired effect either using local (most likely broadcasted) variables or `joins`.

Comment: Hi dear, thanks for response. This is an example of my test_proc, may be you can help me more on this:

def test_proc(x:Int, y:Int):Int = {

val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);

val z:Int = hiveContext.sql("select 7").first.getString(0);
return z }

Comment: I added a clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear for your response.
Basically I am trying to write a store proc for my warehouse. This store proc contains multiple variables to store output of multiple queries and do some manipulation and returns one digit as output. I use this output to filer rows from one fact table.

So I can't do join in my query which use this UDF. One solution what I feel that somehow I should pass my sparkcontext to my UDF and it might work. 

Do you know any use case like this where we can pass sparkcontext as a parameter to a UDF?

Comment: It is not possible. It simply a matter of architecture.